# Force two Onclick triggers to fire an event one time only

Tags: javascript, function, events, onclick, toggle

I have a filter menu with three levels of filtering that I want to setup like this:

Click an option from level one > Level two slides out
Click an option from level two > Option three slides out

The issue that I'm having currently is that all the items in a level are "triggers" for the onClick event...and changing a level option causes the next level menu to slide back in where I would need it to sat out once it's out.

View it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RevConcept/JW5Mm/1/

Here is my code (note, the onClick event is only setup for Level one triggering level two right now)...

HTML

```
<div id="options" class="combo-filters">

                <div class="option-combo location">
                  <ul class="filter option-set group " data-filter-group="location"> 
                    <li class="hidden"><a href="#filter-location-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">any</a>

                      <li><a href="#filter-location-exterior" data-filter-value=".exterior" class="trigger">exterior</a>

                      <li><a href="#filter-location-interior" data-filter-value=".interior" class="trigger">interior</a>
                  </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="option-combo illumination">
                  <ul class="filter option-set group toggle" data-filter-group="illumination"> 
                    <li class="hidden"><a href="#filter-illumination-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">any</a>

                      <li><a href="#filter-illumination-illuminated" data-filter-value=".illuminated">illuminated</a>

                      <li><a href="#filter-illumination-non-illuminated" data-filter-value=".non-illuminated">non-illuminated</a>

                  </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="option-combo mount">
                  <ul class="filter option-set group " data-filter-group="mount"> 
                    <li class="hidden"><a href="#filter-mount-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">any</a>

                      <li><a href="#filter-mount-wall" data-filter-value=".wall">wall</a>

                      <li><a href="#filter-mount-ground" data-filter-value=".ground">ground</a>

                  </ul>
                </div>


            </div><!--end options-->
```

CSS

```
header nav ul.toggle {
display:none;
```

}

JavaScript

```
$(".trigger").one('click', function(){
    $(".toggle").slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a variable in the callback to determine whether it is called and return if it has been called once already.

Comment: Learn Javascript first then :)